# Email address lookup in SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, indexing, database-design

We have a large subscriber database and have a lookup based on email address of type `nvarchar(100)`. It sometimes times out probably because of a large scan of it.

```
var existingEmails =
    _subscriptionsRepository.DataContext
                            .Subscriptions
                            .Where(q => q.Email != null && 
                                        q.Email.ToLower().Equals(model.Email.ToLower()))
                            .ToList();
```

I want to improve this, but weary of some of the options.  Would an index on it be ok, I can handle the additional storage if needed, or a computed column to say grab the domain part. What is a fast way to lookup a row based on an email address of hundreds of thousands?

Comment: I would start with direct index on email-column.

Comment: What's the collation on the database? As you're converting both the column and the search term to lower case, an index may not help. But if collation is case insensitive, that step isn't necessary and just removing it will probably improve the response times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what an index is for. Add an index. However: for an index to work optimally, it needs to be an equality (or at least, range) filter *of the values stored in the index*; and `LCASE(Foo)`/`LOWER(Foo)` etc doesn't qualify. Assuming that your database is running in case-sensitive mode, it would be better to store the data in the normalized form (lower-case, or whatever) **when you store it**, then perform the same normalization on the data you're searching by, allowing you just just use an equality test on the database, i.e.

```cs
var normalizedEmail = YourNormalizationMethodHere(model.Email);
var matches = _subscriptionsRepository.DataContext.Subscriptions.Where(
    q => q.NormalizedEmail != null && q.NormalizedEmail == normalizedEmail);
```

(but even just having the data *in an index* can help performance, even with functions like `LCASE`/`LOWER`, as it can reduce the page reads required)

Comment: We should also note that most databases are **not** case sensitive here. The `ToLower()` call was probably not needed in the first place, and (assuming there's already an index) removing it is all he needs to do.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that is a configuration option, though, so it really depends on the consumer; I'm not sure we can say anything about "most" without asking Microsoft for numbers (if they know and will tell us), and even then: "most" doesn't help if you're not in that group. But yes, I did add the caveat "assuming that your database is running in case-sensitive mode"

Answer (score 0):

@MarcGravelli is obviously right.

It's hard to be sure, but my guess is that the problem with your query is that it has to convert hundreds of thousands of email addresses to lower case, and then compare them with your search term. It's possible that the conversion is more expensive than the search itself.

As Marc says, normalizing the data before storing it is *much* better.

If that's not possible, you could introduce a computed column with the lower case version of the address, and add an index to that column. You can then do your searches against that column.

This is, of course, a bit of a hack, and will likely lead to maintenance challenges, but it may be a short-term solution.